# RuntimeError: Error: Image too small when setting render region, rendering in python

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, render-border

I'm trying to write a python script that automatically sets the render region, like so:

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.use_border = True
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.border_max_y = ymax
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.border_min_y = ymin
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.border_min_x = xmin
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.border_max_x = xmax
```

However, upon trying to render the image from the script (`bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)`), I receive an error: "RuntimeError: Error: Image too small" (no matter the size of the render region).
When I instead try to render the image by hitting F12, it says "Report: Error -- No border area selected".
The errors do not occur when I adjust the render region manually.

I'm using Blender 2.90.1.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Inverted min, max, maybe?

Comment: @lemon Good god, that really was it. Thanks!